# Multiple dpkg postinst script and other errors while upgrading Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04, dpkg

This is the `apt-get upgrade` output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucftmp' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up grub-pc (2.02-2ubuntu8.2) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up gdm3 (3.28.2-0ubuntu1.3) ...
dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 installed gdm3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up unattended-upgrades (1.1ubuntu1.18.04.5) ...
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 installed unattended-upgrades package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up google-chrome-stable (68.0.3440.75-1) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot scan directory '/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 installed google-chrome-stable package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up console-setup-linux (1.178ubuntu2.3) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot scan directory '/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 installed console-setup-linux package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on console-setup-linux | console-setup-freebsd | hurd; however:
  Package console-setup-linux is not configured yet.
  Package console-setup-freebsd is not installed.
  Package hurd is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 gdm3
 unattended-upgrades
 google-chrome-stable
 console-setup-linux
 console-setup
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Very simple. As the errors that you receive such as "Package console-setup-linux is not configured yet" allude to, your applications have not yet been configured. Do so with:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

then try upgrading again. if it gives you the error that you "have held broken packages" input:

`sudo apt -f install`

then run `sudo apt upgrade`

note: `apt-get` is no longer necessary. You can simply type `sudo apt upgrade` for example and accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Do not forget to run `sudo apt full-upgrade` to upgrade your system fully